# error when I import useContext to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to import the value of useContext but I am getting this error :

```
  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

What I am missing here ?

AllThemeContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
export const AllContext = createContext();

const AllContextProvider = (props) => {
  const submittedInput = props.submittedInput;

  return (
    <AllContext.Provider value={{ submittedInput }}>
      {props.children}
    </AllContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AllContextProvider;
```

logo.js

```
import React from "react";
import AllContextProvider from "../context/AllThemeContext";
import "./Logo.scss";
// Component
const Logo = () => {
  return (
    <AllContextProvider.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        console.log(context);
      }}
    </AllContextProvider.Consumer>
  );
};
export default Logo;
```

Comment: But without the consumer, how I am supposed to take the value and print it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `AllContext` from `AllThemeContext` which is the [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and not the default export.

```
import React from "react";
import { AllContext } from "../context/AllThemeContext";
import "./Logo.scss";
// Component
const Logo = () => {
  return (
    <AllContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        console.log(context);
      }}
    </AllContext.Consumer>
  );
};
export default Logo;
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much, it is a little confusing because in the context there are two exports, and I didn't know I should export the context.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't return anything in the children of `AllContextProvider.Consumer`.

You need add return component:

```
  {(context) => {
    console.log(context);
    return <div>Hello world</div>
  }}
```

Comment: Good to know Viet, thanks, but it didn't solve my issue unfortunately.